# Nopcommerce 4.5 - add a button "buy now" under products in catalog that takes them to the respective product page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nopcommerce

This may sound to be a noob question but I'mm clueless on how to do it.

I got the buttons added to the product page like this.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkxzz.png)

How can I add the links to the respective products?

Here's what has been done for this:

```
using Nop.Services.Cms;
using Nop.Services.Plugins;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Infrastructure;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.BuyNowButton
{
    public class BuyButtonPlugin : BasePlugin, IWidgetPlugin
    {
        public bool HideInWidgetList => false;

        public override async Task InstallAsync()
        {
            await base.InstallAsync();
        }
        public override async Task UninstallAsync()
        {
            await base.UninstallAsync();
        }
        string IWidgetPlugin.GetWidgetViewComponentName(string widgetZone)
        {
            return "BuyNowButton";
        }
        public Task<IList<string>> GetWidgetZonesAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult<IList<string>>(new List<string>
            { PublicWidgetZones.ProductBoxAddinfoAfter});
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<style>
    
    .buynow{
        height: 32px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 6px;
        background-color: #e3521b;
    }
    .btn{
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: none;
    }
</style>

    <div class="buynow">
        <span class="btn">Buy Now</span>
        
    </div>
```

Component:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Components;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.BuyNowButton.Components
{
    [ViewComponent(Name = "BuyNowButton")]
    public class BuyNowButtonComponent : NopViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View("~/Plugins/Widgets.BuyNowButton/Views/BuyNowButton.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is the correct way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You need sename of product. You can check _ProductBox.cshtml view. In ProductOverviewModel model there is already sename property. Change component to this:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string widgetZone, object additionalData)
    {
        if (additionalData.GetType() != typeof(ProductOverviewModel))
            return Content("");

        var productOverviewModel = additionalData as ProductOverviewModel;

        var product = await _productService.GetProductByIdAsync(productOverviewModel.Id);
        if (product == null)
            return Content("");

        return View(productOverviewModel);
    }
```

Then in the view you can use sename like this:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = Model.SeName })"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question: Do you mean I must change my whole component and replace it with the code you gave me?

Comment: just receive ProductOverviewModel then pass to view.